# Adding a master x-axis title to a multipanel grid of plots using ggdraw(), plot_grid() and ggsave() works in pdf but not jpg

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I am creating a large 2 x 4 multi-graph panel using the packages described in the title. I have created a separate object as a master x-axis title spanning the graphs using `ggdraw()` and `draw_label()` from the cowplot package, which I have placed underneath two rows of graphs using `plot_grid()`. I have created a simplified version of this using toy data below

```
# create the axis title object
xTitle = ggdraw() +
           draw_label("lorem ipsum",
                      fontface = "bold",
                      hjust = 0.5) +
           theme(plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,7))

# create graphs
ggplot(data = iris,
       mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Width,
                     y = Sepal.Length)) +
       geom_point() -> p1

ggplot(data = iris,
       mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Width,
                     y = Sepal.Length)) +
       geom_point() -> p2

# create the grid 
grid <- cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, xTitle, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1,1,0.2))
```

Now when you print this object in rstudio...

```
grid
```

[image]

...or as a pdf...

```
# save it as pdf
ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "panel.pdf",
                plot = grid,
                device = "pdf",
                dpi = "retina", 
                width = 30,
                height = 15,
                units = "cm")
```

...it looks great[image]

However when you save it as a jpg it excludes the bottom object of the grid

```
# save it as jpg
ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "panel.jpg",
                plot = grid,
                device = "jpg",
                dpi = "retina", 
                width = 30,
                height = 15,
                units = "cm")
```

[image]

**Does anyone know how to print the jpg so it doesn't exclude the bottom object, or give advice about what I'm doing wrong *or* offer an alternative way of achieving the same result?**

Here is my session info

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] multcomp_1.4-20 TH.data_1.1-1   MASS_7.3-58.1   survival_3.4-0  mvtnorm_1.1-3  
 [6] cowplot_1.1.1   emmeans_1.8.0   nlme_3.1-159    forcats_0.5.2   stringr_1.4.1  
[11] dplyr_1.0.10    purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0     tibble_3.1.8   
[16] ggplot2_3.3.6   tidyverse_1.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lubridate_1.8.0     lattice_0.20-45     zoo_1.8-10          digest_0.6.29      
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1    utf8_1.2.2          R6_2.5.1            cellranger_1.1.0   
 [9] backports_1.4.1     reprex_2.0.2        coda_0.19-4         httr_1.4.4         
[13] pillar_1.8.1        rlang_1.0.6         googlesheets4_1.0.1 readxl_1.4.1       
[17] rstudioapi_0.14     Matrix_1.4-1        labeling_0.4.2      textshaping_0.3.6  
[21] splines_4.2.2       googledrive_2.0.0   munsell_0.5.0       broom_1.0.1        
[25] compiler_4.2.2      modelr_0.1.9        systemfonts_1.0.4   pkgconfig_2.0.3    
[29] tidyselect_1.2.0    codetools_0.2-18    fansi_1.0.3         crayon_1.5.1       
[33] tzdb_0.3.0          dbplyr_2.2.1        withr_2.5.0         grid_4.2.2         
[37] jsonlite_1.8.0      xtable_1.8-4        gtable_0.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.3    
[41] DBI_1.1.3           magrittr_2.0.3      scales_1.2.1        estimability_1.4.1 
[45] cli_3.3.0           stringi_1.7.8       farver_2.1.1        fs_1.5.2           
[49] xml2_1.3.3          ragg_1.2.2          ellipsis_0.3.2      generics_0.1.3     
[53] vctrs_0.4.1         sandwich_3.0-2      tools_4.2.2         glue_1.6.2         
[57] hms_1.1.2           colorspace_2.0-3    gargle_1.2.0        rvest_1.0.3        
[61] haven_2.5.1
```

Comment: Your example worked as expected on my system. Perhaps try "device = jpeg" instead of "device = jpg"? Are you able to please edit your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as expected if you open and close the jpeg device, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     stamp
# create the axis title object
xTitle = ggdraw() +
  draw_label("lorem ipsum",
             fontface = "bold",
             hjust = 0.5) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,7))

# create graphs
ggplot(data = iris,
       mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Width,
                     y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() -> p1

ggplot(data = iris,
       mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Width,
                     y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() -> p2

# create the grid 
grid <- cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, xTitle, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1,1,0.2))

jpeg(filename = "test.jpg", width = 30, height = 15, units = "cm", res = 300)
grid
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image: image.jpeg]

---

Does that approach work on your system? Or do you still 'lose' the bottom title?

Comment: Thanks for the help @jared_mamrot. Do you know why it doesn't work with `ggsave()`?

Comment: Not sure @llewmills, I suspect it's a 'Windows thing'. I tried a bunch of different ways to reproduce the issue and couldn't. I can't see any obvious red flags in your `sessionInfo()`. The only other thing I can think of is to explicitly 'print' the plot in ggsave (e.g. https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/152#issuecomment-763435495): `ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "panel.jpg", plot = plot(grid, newpage = FALSE), device = "jpeg", dpi = "retina", width = 30, height = 15, units = "cm")`